# Java 17 - Json object becomes empty when trying to write its content to a file and upload to S3

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, java-17

I have a lambda function written in Java 17 that triggers when a json file is uploaded into an S3 bucket. The json uploaded contains AWS resource names for multiple services like DynamoDB, RDS etc. The lambda function then fetches service and CloudWatch metrics for those services and puts them inside a new json object. Finally the json object is written into a file and uploaded to another S3 bucket.

The problem I'm facing is that when I try to write the json object to a file and upload it I'm getting a json object without the metrics. They're not being fetched. As soon as I remove the code that tries to write the json to the file and only print out the json object in the console it seems fine. Here's my code(snippets):

```
public class S3JsonReader implements RequestHandler<S3Event, String> {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    private final AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build();

    private final DynamoDBMetricsRetriever dynamoDBCWMetricsRetriever;

    public S3JsonReader() {

        this.dynamoDBCWMetricsRetriever = new DynamoDBMetricsRetriever();
    
    }

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(S3Event event, Context context) {
        try {
            if (event.getRecords() == null || event.getRecords().isEmpty()) {
                return "No S3 records found in the event.";
            }

            String startTime = null;
            String endTime = null;
            List<String> dynamoDBList = new ArrayList<>();
        

            for (S3Event.S3EventNotificationRecord record : event.getRecords()) {
                String bucketName = record.getS3().getBucket().getName();
                String objectKey = record.getS3().getObject().getKey();
                S3Object s3Object = s3.getObject(bucketName, objectKey);
                String jsonContent = new String(s3Object.getObjectContent().readAllBytes());
                JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(jsonContent);
                startTime = jsonNode.get("startTime").asText();
                endTime = jsonNode.get("endTime").asText();

                JsonNode resourceNamesNode = jsonNode.get("resourceNames");
                if (resourceNamesNode != null && resourceNamesNode.isObject()) {
                    Iterator<String> fieldNames = resourceNamesNode.fieldNames();
                    while (fieldNames.hasNext()) {
                        String fieldName = fieldNames.next();
                        JsonNode fieldValue = resourceNamesNode.get(fieldName);

                        if (fieldValue != null && fieldValue.isArray()) {
                            for (JsonNode valueNode : fieldValue) {
                                switch (fieldName) {
                                    case "dynamoDB":
                                        dynamoDBList.add(valueNode.asText());
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Map<String, Map<String, Object>> dynamoDBMetricsMap = new HashMap<>();
  
            for (String dynamoDBResource : dynamoDBList) {
                Map<String, Object> dynamoDBMetrics = dynamoDBMetricsHandler.getDynamoDBMetrics(dynamoDBResource);
                dynamoDBMetricsMap.put(dynamoDBResource, dynamoDBMetrics);
            }

            Map<String, Object> finalResult = new HashMap<>();
            finalResult.put("startTime", startTime);
            finalResult.put("endTime", endTime);
            finalResult.put("dynamoDBMetrics", dynamoDBMetricsMap);
       

            String jsonResult = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(finalResult);
            System.out.println("Final JSON Result:\n" + jsonResult);
            String s3BucketName = System.getenv("S3_BUCKET_NAME");
            String objectKey = "result.json";

            File tempFile = File.createTempFile("jsonResult", ".json");
            
            try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile))) {
                writer.write(jsonResult);
                s3.putObject(s3BucketName, objectKey, tempFile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Error writing JSON result to file: " + e.getMessage();
            }
        
            return "Successfully processed S3 event.";
         } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              return "Error reading and processing JSON file: " + e.getMessage();
         }
     }
}
```

In the above code, I removed code for other services and left DynamoDB only for reference. I have another class which actually handles getting the metrics but the code there works fine.
So with the code above, I get an empty JSON object like this:

```
{
    "RDSMetrics": {},
    "startTime": "2023-09-14T10:12:22Z",
    "endTime": "2023-09-14T19:29:34Z",
}
```

This is the print result from `System.out.println("Final JSON Result:\n" + jsonResult);`.

As soon as I remove this bit:

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("jsonResult", ".json");

try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile))) {
    writer.write(jsonResult);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return "Error writing JSON result to file: " + e.getMessage();
}
```

I get the following result in `System.out.println("Final JSON Result:\n" + jsonResult);`

```
{
   "RDSMetrics": {
      "BillingAndScalingMode": "Provisioned",
      "MaxWriteCapacityUnits": 50,
      "MinWriteCapacityUnits": 10  
    },
   "startTime": "2023-09-14T10:12:22Z",
   "endTime": "2023-09-14T19:29:34Z",
}
```

This is what I expect this lambda function to do. However when I use the above code to try to write the json object to a file and upload it to S3 the metrics are not being retrieved.

I also tried another way to write the json object to a file and upload it:

```
byte[] jsonBytes = jsonResult.getBytes("UTF-8");
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonBytes);
ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
metadata.setContentLength(jsonBytes.length);
s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(s3BucketName, objectKey, inputStream,
metadata));
```

With this code I am getting the same result, meaning the json object does not include the metrics.
What am I doing wrong and how can I get this to work?

EDIT:
I found out that the only line that really affects the code is `s3.putObject(s3BucketName, objectKey, tempFile);`. When this line is commented out I am seeing data in jsonResult. When I uncomment `s3.putObject(s3BucketName, objectKey, tempFile);` I get no data inside the json object again

Comment: Your first code snippet does not upload anything. All it does, is writing a string to a temporary file. And you’re saying that removing the code that writes the string to a temporary file changes the contents of the string. That’s hard to believe. It’s also hard to believe that the object mapper changes the map key `"dynamoDBMetrics"` to `"RDSMetrics"`.

Comment: I added the missing piece and also found out something more about the code which I described in the edit

Comment: There is no point in incrementally changing the code snippet in your question to make it look correct, when it only makes clear that this is absolutely not the code you have problems with. You should post the actual code that exhibited the described behavior.